# invoke ! (bang) method on right operand

Tags: scala

I am able to define a prefix operator named ! for my type with no argument and also I am able to invoke !: method on right operand using the following code:

```
class Cool {
    private var counter = 0

    def unary_!(): Unit = {
        counter += 1;
        println("Counter by ! is " + counter)
    }

    def !:(num: Int): Unit = {
        counter += num;
        println("Counter by !: is " + counter)
    }
}


object CoolApp extends App{
    val cool = new Cool
    ! cool // Prints "Counter by ! is 1"
    ! cool // Prints "Counter by ! is 2"
    12 !: cool // Prints "Counter by !: is 14"
}
```

However instead of !: method I am interested to have a ! method (that applies to right operand):

```
12 ! cool
```

Knowing that I need a : at the end of method name for applying it to right operand is there a solution so I can have ! instead of !: ?

In summary I'd like to increment counter by one when using ! with no left operand and increment by left operand when there is a left operand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Cool {
    private var counter = 0

    def unary_!(): Unit = {
        counter += 1;
        println("Counter by ! is " + counter)
    }

    def incrementBy(num: Int): Unit = {
        counter += num;
        println("Counter by incrementBy is " + counter)
    }
}


implicit class BangInt(val self: Int) extends AnyVal { 
    def ! (c: Cool): Unit = c incrementBy self 
}
```

You can add your `!` method to `Int` via implicit conversion, and this will work as expected.

```
scala> val cool = new Cool
cool: Cool = Cool@d71adc2

scala> 21 ! cool
Counter by incrementBy is 21
```